# Will a crawler work on this server configuration?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hosting, web-crawler

I am building a small crawler as a hobby project. All I want to do is crawl around a million pages and store them in a database. (yes it will be updated time to time, but entries at any particular time will be 1 million only) Just to know how these things work.

I want to code it in PHP/MySQL. I **don't want** any search capabilities as I don't have server resources to provide that. All I want is, I should be able to run few SQL queries on database by myself.

In database I won't be storing any Page text (that I want to be stored in separate txt files - I don't know if it will be feasible). Only title, link and some other information will be stored. So basically, if I run a query and it gives me some results I can pull the text data from these files.

Would like to know if this design will be feasible in following environment.

I will be purchasing a VPS from Linode (512 MB RAM) (I can't go for dedicated server, and shared hosts won't let me do this).

**My Question:** Will it be able to sustain this big database (1 million rows) with ability to run queries in batch mode when required.

Any kind of suggestions welcome. Any other hosting option will also be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this should be helpful http://www.sphider.eu/

Comment: A million pages will take a while. I hope your ISP doesn't mind.

Comment: @experimentX I want to custom make it from scratch to learn few database, crawling and scalability issues. Thanks for your link though :)

Comment: @the Tin Man Thats why I am going for VPS. It will have a bandwidth of few hundred GBs and ya. The crawl can go for few week, Its not an issue.

Comment: Make sure you keep track of visited URLs in your database, and normalize your URLs so you don't get into loops because of session keys or your "few weeks" can get a lot longer with no real progress. Also be sure to honor good web-spider behavior recommendations.

Comment: point out which of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crawler+php you already looked at and the refine your question to only ask what those dont answer already.

Comment: @Gordon I am just asking if my server (linode VPS 512 MB) will able to sustain the load. :)

Comment: @Ankit how about rephrasing the question title then to reflect that then ;)

Comment: @Gordon Sorry for that. Title changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a web crawler from scratch is a considerable undertaking, at least if you wish to crawl millions of pages. I know this from personal experience on the [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org) web crawler.

You may benefit from reading the "[Overview of the crawler](http://crawler.archive.org/articles/developer_manual/overview.html)" chapter from the Heritrix developer guide. That chapter covers the high level design and should help you figure out the basic components of a crawler.

Simply put this boils down to 'crawl state' and 'processing'. The crawl state is URLs you´ve seen, URLs you've crawled etc. While processing covers the fetching of an URL and subsequent processing to extract links, save downloaded data etc. Multiple processing threads are typically run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Going through it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org). It's fast, and it'll work fine on a Linode 512M server, but it's written in Python.